# Creating a visible timer on experiment stimulus in psychopy

Tags: timer, psychopy

New to the forum, thanks in advance for any help you could provide.
I have a series of .jpgs that are being presented to users as they study the info contained within. Instructions state that each jpg can be studied for a max of 120secs. I've already coded it such that the jpg will advance after the 120sec limit:

```
    RespKey= []
    RT = []
    event.clearEvents()
    myClock.reset()
    t1example = myClock.getTime()
    t2example = t1example
    while t2example < (t1example+120):    # value added to t1 here is timeout value; 
        RespKey = event.getKeys(keyList=["space"], timeStamped=myClock) # they are told to press space bar when done studying
        if len(RespKey) > 0:
            RT = RespKey[0][1]
            Resp =  RespKey[0][0].lower()
            print Resp
            print RT
            break
        else:
            t2study = myClock.getTime()      # end of timeout loop
    myWin.flip()
```

The problem is, I don't know how to make the Clock/ Timer/ Stopwatch function visible to the user while studying the jpg. Is there a way to superimpose a visible clock onto the stimulus so nobody is surprised when the study time comes to an end?

*Note: New to coding, please couch jargon in layman speak if at all possible.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Before the loop (and before re-setting the clock), create a text stimulus like this:

```
clockText = visual.TextStim(myWin) # include other parameters if you want to change the default size, font, etc
```

Then on every frame, you will update the content of that stimulus. i.e. just prior to the myWin.flip() call, do this:

```
clockText.setText(str(t2study)) # you can format/round this as required
clockText.draw()
```

Check the face_jpg.py Coder demo for an example of displaying text like this on every frame.

Comment: To elaborate: You would want to put the myWin.flip() and Michael's code within the loop (indent it one step) to make it update continuously.